# Css help? Images on hover

Tags: css, click, hover, overlap, onhover

Hey guys i need help with some css i have some images that expand when i hover over them but it pushes everything away at the same time

```
        <style>
    .box
{
   width: 750px;
   height: 1000px;
   border:1px solid green;


}
.enlarge-onhover {
     width: 125px;
     height: 125px;
}

.enlarge-onhover:hover {
     width: 225px;
     height: 225px;
}
</style>
```

I dont want it to do that i want it to just overlap the rest of the images and to expand on a left click rather than hover

Comment: Try using a `float` tag? Such as `float:right`. In my opinion, you should use JQuery for this.

Comment: Changing it to a click action requires javascript or you can play with the active pseudo class but I would recommend jquery for ease and control

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this is to use [Absolute positioning](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp).

The problem is, as you're hovering, your changing the sizes (width and height), so it will move everything across and re-render the page.

Answer (score 0):

You could use javascript (jquery to do this for you) if you wanted it to happen `onclick`.

You would have to put `position: absolute;` on your image for it not to disturb other elements.

```
$(".enlarge-onhover").click(function() {

      $(this).css({width: 255, height: 255});
});
```

If you just want it to happen on hover then just add `position: absolute;` to your image's css.

If you are not using jquery and just pure javascript you can achieve the same thing by doing;

```
var img = document.getElementById("myImg");

img.addEventListener("click", function() {

    img.style.width = "255px";
    img.style.height = "225px";
}, false);
```

The above assumes of course that your image has an id of `myImg`.

Answer (score -1):

As well as positioning the images along the X and Y axes, you can also set Z axis to make elements appear one on top of another.

I think the solution is to increase the **z-index** of the element on hover as
       z-index: 50;

You will need to reset the z-index to 0 once the user *un-hovers*

This when combined with setting the position of the hovered/enlarged image to look like the thumbnail is enlarging, will do the trick for you.

You can read more about z-index here:
    http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: This will still push the other elements away!

Comment: Even if it's combined with making the position absolute?